# Are both $g', g$ assumed to be surjective in the commutative diagram for $3 \times 3$ lemma?

Tags: modules, exact-sequence, morphism

The following is taken from *Module Theory An Approach to Linear Algebra}* by T.S. Blyth

$\style{font-family:inherit;}{\color{Green}{\textbf{Background:}}}$

**Theorem 3.4:**

Consider the diagram

[image]

of $R$-modules and $R$-morphisms in which $f$ is an $R$-epimorphism.  The following conditions are equivalent:

$(1)$ there is a unique $R$-morphism $h:B\to C$ such that $h\cdot f=g$;

$(2)$ $\text{ker }f\subset \text{ker }g$.

Moreover, such an $R$-morphism $h$ is an monomorphism if and only if $\ker f= \ker g$.

**Exercise 3.10: [The 3x3 lemma]**  Consider the following diagram of $R$-modules and $R$-morphisms
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
@. 0 @. 0 @. 0 \\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
0 @>>> A' @>{\smash{\alpha'}}>> A @>{\smash{\beta'}}>> A'' @>>> 0 \\
@. @VV{f'}V @VV{f}V @VV{f''}V \\
0 @>>> B' @>{\smash{\alpha}}>> B @>{\smash{\beta}}>> B'' @>>> 0 \\
@. @VV{g'}V @VV{g}V @VV{g''}V \\
0 @>>> C' @. C @. C'' @>>> 0 \\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
@. 0 @. 0 @. 0\end{CD}

Given that this diagram is commutative, that all three columns are exact and that the top two rows are exact, prove that there exist unique $R$-morphisms $\alpha'': C'\to C$ and  $\beta'': C\to C''$ such that the resulting bottom row is exact and the complete diagram is commutative.

[*Hint.* Observe that $g\circ \alpha \circ f' = 0$ so that $\ker g' = \operatorname{im}f' \subset \ker g \circ \alpha$. Use Theorem 3.4 to produce $\alpha''$. Argue similarly to produce $\beta''$.  Now chase!]

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

In the hint for the above exercise (3.10), it cites theorem 3.4 for producing $\alpha'',\beta'',$ after stating that $\ker g' = \operatorname{im}f' \subset \ker g \circ \alpha.$  But the equivalent of $\ker g'$ in theorem 3.4 is $\ker f$, and $f$ in theorem 3.4 is assume to be a $R$-epimorphism and hence surjective.  This in turn would make $g'$ to be surjective for the hint to exercise 3.4. Similarly for $g$ in the case of $\beta''$.  Since $g',g$ have to assume to be surjective even though it was not made explicit in the hypothesis of the exercsie, can I assume it to be so when doing the exercise. I am not sure why these two minor facts are not made explicit?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The exactness of the columns implies that $g'$ and $g$ are surjective. For if $0 \to A \xrightarrow{f} B \xrightarrow{g} C \to 0$ is exact, then $\operatorname{im} g = \operatorname{ker}(C \to 0) = C$, so $g$ is surjective. Likewise, we also have that $f'$ and $f$ are injective.

Comment: @feynhat from the same reasoning as yours, I can infer that $g''$ is surjective and $f''$ is also injective? I forgot about the exactness of $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0.$

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @feynhat ah kk thank you.  I forgot that for short exact sequences, injection and surjection can both be inferred.